# armitage teamserver tthrowing connection refused on startup ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql, metasploit

I tried every possible answer online! It was running sometime back.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Error:

```
Warning: checkError(): java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) at server.sl:450
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it. Please show the code causing the error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when I run ./teamserver my-VPS-IP password ... it throws error